# I have created a new page in Ionic 5 but I can't the path URL

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5

I have created a new page in my Ionic5 project but I cant find the path/URL. When I navigate it says: http://localhost:8100/page-not-found

Within the file structure I added where my other pages are:
src and then app. The other original pages I can navigate to but not the new one

What could be the issue?

Comment: check your `app.routing-module.ts` file to get your new page URL.

Comment: Hi Najam....if I look in app.routing-module.ts I see
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then( m => m.HomePageModule)
  }

Comment: so your path will be `/home`

Comment: Thanks Najam but I have tried it but it doesnt work